# git: Allow specific files in a commit to be allowed via push to the remote repository based on certain criteria

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit

I have a situation wherein my pre-receive hook script needs to allow only those files in commits whose name starts with `Tag_`

For example, I have a commit which contains 3 files,

```
Tag_a
Tagb
Tag_c
```

now my pre-receive script should allow only `Tag_a` and `Tag_b` but not `Tagb`.

I read somewhere on Stack Overflow that if we reject a file and allow the other files to be pushed, then the hash (sha1) value of the commit may change.

So my question is, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: A quick help/tip/suggestion would be highly appreciated :) Thanks in advance..

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled: you want to reject a commit (regardless of any branch or tag reference names) if any directory/ies within the commit contain (or don't contain) a *file* whose name starts with `Tag_`?

Comment: i want to reject a particular file in a list of files, which are in a commit among list of commits, which does not start with Tag_. I need to reject only that particular file, while allowing all the other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `pre-receive` or `update` hook can only accept or reject an entire ref-name.  It's an all or nothing deal.  You can inspect the proposed tree(s), but you'll have to figure out what the changes from the previous place the ref-name pointed-to might be.

For instance, if you get something saying `refs/heads/zog` is moving from `d4df144c36f26c7887e5f8a74812f06a3b0338ec` to `5e013711f5d6eb3f643ef562d49a131852aa4aa1`, you'll need to see all the commits being added (or removed) between those points, and see what tree changes are being made in each commit.  You can then decide that it's OK for the branch name to change, or that it is not OK, and that's basically it.  The new commit might have the old one as its (single) parent, or it might have another new commit as its parent, which in turn has a third new commit, etc.  (And any new commit may be a merge with multiple parents.)

Comment: suppose if i have 30 commits, each containing 5 files, and the 25th commit has a file whose name starts with Tagb(or something). Then what ur trying to say is push denies(pre-receive hook) all the commits, am i right?

Comment: Technically, if you deny an update in `update`, it actually only keeps the reference from moving.  The new commits wind up in the repo, just without a ref-name.  If you deny in `pre-receive` it keeps *all* references from moving.  In many cases there's only one reference change per push, but if someone pushes three branches and five tags, you can reject all at once (`pre-receive`) or ref-by-ref (`update`).  But in effect, yes.

Comment: ok, i completely got your point.. But isnt this annoying.. I mean, can this be reported as a bug or something??? Just curious to know..

Comment: It's the way it's meant to work.  In general, hooks are not supposed to *change* your work, only to *use* (or deny) it in some way.  Some can be bent into changing things pretty easily, but the pre-receive and update hooks shouldn't, as the side doing the push will think that all changes were taken in as-is if the push succeeds.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answers.. Helped me understand the hooks better.. Really appreciate.. :)

Comment: I wrote a lot of hooks for previous $work.  The documentation then was terrible, and it's still a little bit wanting, I think. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't be sneaky. Just reject the whole commit, user should `--amend` commit to exclude disallowed files and try to push again.

Comment: the situation may arise wherein i have 50 files in a commit, and if one file with proper filename doesnt satisfy the criteria, then all files gets denied. so is there no alternative to this?

Comment: Reject commit, saying user to exclude the file, user amends the commit and pushes again the 49 files. Why does it worry you?

Comment: the thing is i want to put this hook at the server side(pre-receive)

Comment: @user2663585 Yes, this is right. The server doesn't accept bad commits. Client should fix commits and push again. Otherwise if you silently mangle commits, it will be a lot of fun for clients.